# What packages provide visual odometry?

Tags: navigation, odometry, visual-odometry, vslam, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a package that provides visual odometry aside from vslam? I found visodo but it has a missing/deleted dependency(vop).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9180/what-packages-provide-visual-odometry?/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-02-23

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We just released our ROS-Wrapper for libviso2, called [viso2_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros). It contains nodes for monocular and stereo odometry. Every parameter from libviso2 can be set through ROS. Odometry information is published as [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) and [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) as well as through a [tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) for easy visualization through [rviz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz). Have a look at the corresponding [ros wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros) for further information.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-03-29**:
I strongly encourage the use of viso2_ros. So far, it is the best visual odometry package I have found in ROS.

**Comment by [Giuseppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2133/giuseppe/) on 2012-04-05**:
Stephan,
do you think it is possible to add the option replace=true as a ros parameter to set at running time? Is it even possible to set parameters without changing those in the program? If yes in which way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe there is a released package providing that functionality at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-03**:
Would this: (http://www.rainsoft.de/software/libviso.html) work with ros? Or is there anybody who had use it with ros perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay ... I have it working, but it is not complete at this point [16 Feb 2012]. I have the mono camera up and running but haven't started on the stereo yet. Feel free to take a look at my github of [libviso2](https://github.com/walchko/libviso2). I will improve it over time.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2011-04-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-09-09**:
Hi! I'm working in visual odometry, did you make the ROS node for libviso? or how did you resolve the Visual Odometry problem?

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-05-04**:
It would be great if you did. To make sure no one else is working on it already it'd be safer to drop a line on pcl-users@code.ros.org and ros-users@code.ros.org.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-02-18**:
The code looks great. I'll try it out today with some cameras I have. Thanks!

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-18**:
Thomas, let me know how it goes for you

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-02-19**:
It was easy to get running for the monocular case.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-02-25**:
@Kevin, if I have changes I'd like to see in your nodes, do you want me to just push them up?

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-25**:
sure ... thanks!